# On Linux, what's the use of installing clang++ if it uses g++ libs only?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, clang++

For C++ development on Linux, if I install clang and use it; it actually uses libstdc++(the g++ lib). What's the use of installing the frontend compiler clang on linux then?

I should be good with gcc/g++ only on a linux machine as that's a complete toolchain!

Note: I'm not an expert in  C++.

Comment: Compiling the same code with different compilers (with all warnings activated) is a good way to improve it and spot possible portability problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libstdc++ is a default runtime on your Linux. libc++ is not installed by default. If you link your app to libc++, you have to add it as a runtime dependency.

You are right, gcc/g++ is good for Linux, moreover its diagnostic messages are more clear, thus the compiler is better for beginners. By using clang++, you need to know the C++ standard deeper, otherwise it's difficult to get an error reason.

Comment: Maybe things have improved but clangs error messages were usually better than gccs